# How to check if keys exists and retrieve value from Dictionary in descending priority

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have a dictionary and I would like to get some values from it based on some keys. For example, I have a dictionary for users with their first name, last name, username, address, age and so on. Let's say, I only want to get one value (name) - either last name or first name or username but in descending priority like shown below:

(1) last name: if key exists, get value and stop checking. If not, move to next key.

(2) first name: if key exists, get value and stop checking. If not, move to next key.

(3) username: if key exists, get value or return null/empty

```
#my dict looks something like this
myDict = {'age': ['value'], 'address': ['value1, value2'],
          'firstName': ['value'], 'lastName': ['']}

#List of keys I want to check in descending priority: lastName > firstName > userName
keySet = ['lastName', 'firstName', 'userName']
```

What I tried doing is to get all the possible values and put them into a list so I can retrieve the first element in the list. Obviously it didn't work out.

```
tempList = []

for key in keys:
    get_value = myDict.get(key)
    tempList .append(get_value)
```

Is there a better way to do this without using if else block?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

One option if the number of keys is small is to use chained gets:

```
value = myDict.get('lastName', myDict.get('firstName', myDict.get('userName')))
```

But if you have keySet defined, this might be clearer:

```
value = None
for key in keySet:
    if key in myDict:
        value = myDict[key]
        break
```

The chained `get`s do not short-circuit, so all keys will be checked but only one used. If you have enough possible keys that the extra lookups matter, use the `for` loop.

Comment: Does this check if the key exists first before trying to retrieve it?

Comment: Yes.  That's that the `in` test does.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how does the value = myDict.get(... part work?

Comment: `get` takes an optional second parameter.  If the key isn't in the dictionary, that second parameter will be returned, or `None` if you didn't specify one.  So if `lastName` isn't in the dict, it'll evaluate the second `get` and so on.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I need. I didn't know I can do that.

Comment: The problem here is that the arguments are evaluated *before* the function call and any logic inside it. Thus, even if `'lastName'` exists in `myDict`, `myDict.get('firstName', myDict.get('userName'))` is evaulated and just thrown away.
`value = myDict.get('lastName') or myDict.get('firstName') or myDict('userName')` is almost equivalent but much more efficient and readable.

Comment: Yes, `get` does not short-circuit. If I were in a situation where that mattered I'd probably use the for loop - if nothing else, the `or` chain will do the wrong thing if the key is in the dictionary with a value that's `False` when evaluated as a boolean. I also dislike using boolean operators for non-boolean purposes, but that's less important.

Answer (score 26):

Use `.get()`, which if the key is not found, returns `None`.

```
for i in keySet:
    temp = myDict.get(i)
    if temp is not None:
        print temp
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

If we encapsulate that in a function we could use recursion and state clearly the purpose by naming the function properly (not sure if `getAny` is actually a good name):

```
def getAny(dic, keys, default=None):
    return (keys or default) and dic.get(keys[0], 
                                         getAny( dic, keys[1:], default=default))
```

or even better, without recursion and more clear:

```
def getAny(dic, keys, default=None):
    for k in keys: 
        if k in dic:
           return dic[k]
    return default
```

Then that could be used in a way similar to the dict.get method, like:

```
getAny(myDict, keySet)
```

and even have a default result in case of no keys found at all:

```
getAny(myDict, keySet, "not found")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `myDict.has_key(keyname)` as well to validate if the key exists.

### Edit based on the comments -

This would work only on versions lower than 3.1. `has_key` has been removed from Python 3.1. You should use the `in` operator if you are using Python 3.1

Comment: Just to update the readers, `has_key` has been removed in Python 3.x, use `keyname in myDict` instead.
https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins

Comment: You should use the `in` operator if you're using Python 2.2 or later, since that's the first version `in` for mapping types was introduced and `has_key` was deprecated.